# How can I write my own POST request in React Dropzone Uploader?

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, dropzone

I am using React Dropzone Uploader in my react application, the getUploadParams method directly uploads the file to the server, which I want to be invoked after clicking a specific submit button. Is there any way to achieve this or to write my own POST request using axios?

Answer (score 0):

You can add onSubmit={handleSubmit} in Dropzone and make your post request in handleSubmit function.

```
const handleSubmit =(files, allFiles)=>{
console.log(files.map(f => f.meta));
    // post call 
}
 <Dropzone
        //other attributes
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
```

Comment: But what changes I have to made in the getUploadParams,can you give a more detailed example with the POST method itself, thanks

Comment: You can share the sample of your code that you are trying.

Comment: I am not able to insert my code here in comment but I am referring to the first code from this link [link](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start)

Answer (score -1):

After reading the RDU api docs,  you might need to manipulate uploads from getUploadParams. See the docs for `getUploadParams` [here](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/api).